# Packet loss for custom domain

Tags: ssl, https, dns, openshift, cloudflare

I have a custom domain (`busymusic.ga`) for `php-javani.rhcloud.com` domain. Because I want a https connection and don't have this feature with custom domain Openshift (that's right?) used CloudFlare. Set CloudFlare DNS address in domain panel, then create a cname record in CloudFlare like this:
[image] 
But know when pinging `busymusic.ga` about 91% of packets lost (test it for long time) while when pinging `php-javani.rhcloud.com` I don't have this problem.

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, but about network issues instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to open a support ticket directly with CloudFlare so our support team can look into this further. P.S. I work at CloudFlare.

Also, to note: ping won't be an accurate measurement if network quality. See: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169826-Why-am-I-seeing-timeouts-pinging-my-site-on-CloudFlare-

We ratelimit ICMP traffic, but that in no way indicates an actual problem.